# Add Custom Header in ASP.net core web api (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -- Version="5.0.0-rc4")

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

I want to add custom header to swagger. I am using asp.net core 3.0 using swagger 5.0.0-rc4.
It would be something like Key: Value that my middleware would receive.

```
public class MyHeaderFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {  
        if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Description = "Authenticate API Key",
                Required = false,

                Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "String",
                    Default = new OpenApiString("Bearer")
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register in Startup.cs :

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.OperationFilter<AuthResponsesOperationFilter>();
};
```

In addition ,it seems you are passing the Authorization header , according to [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1295) and [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1277) threads :

> The Authorization header parameter defined in /auth/credentials and /system/info won't be used because OpenAPI Specification says that tools should ignore explicit header parameters named Authorization. The Authorization header should be defined as a security scheme instead.

Comment: Thankyou so much but I have already registered it in startup class . I wanted to add a custom header like Key : Value like we do it in postman we give the key Name and Key Value and i am  using the version of swagger  5.0.0-rc4 @Nan Yu

Comment: Authorization as name can't be passed as shown in my reply , you can change name and that should be passed .